# JLabel paints dots

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo
{
    JFrame jf;
    JLabel[] labels;
    JPanel panel;

    public Demo()
    {
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        labels = new JLabel[10];
        Box vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new JLabel();
            vbox.add(labels[i]);
        }
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(vbox);
        jf.add(panel);
        jf.setSize(300, 250);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DemoRunnable());
    }
    public void updateState()
    {
        for (JLabel l : labels)
        {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5)
                l.setText("777777777777777777777777777777777777");
            else
                l.setText("10000000000000000000000000000000000000");
        }
    }
}
class DemoRunnable implements Runnable
{
    Demo demo;

    DemoRunnable()
    {
        this.demo = new Demo();
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(0);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    demo.updateState();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
}
```

I see such effect when this program is perfomed. Is it possible to eliminate it(zeroes must be instead dots)?

[image]

Comment: This is basically because your text is overflowing `JLabel`'s bounds.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my code in answer is example only,

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo {

    private JFrame jf;
    private JLabel[] labels;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Demo() {
        labels = new JLabel[10];
        Box vbox = Box.createVerticalBox();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            labels[i] = new JLabel();
            labels[i].setText("10000000000000000000000000000000000000");
            vbox.add(labels[i]);
        }
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        panel.add(vbox);
        jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(panel);
        jf.pack();
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DemoRunnable());
    }

    public void updateState() {
        for (final JLabel l : labels) {
            if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        l.setText("777777777777777777777777777777777777");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        l.setText("10000000000000000000000000000000000000");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}

class DemoRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Demo demo;

    DemoRunnable() {
        this.demo = new Demo();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(250);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    demo.updateState();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for `invokeLater()`, and a good illustration of why `javax.swing.Timer` is so convenient.

Comment: @trashgod agreed was +1, but I think that OP don't understand how the FlowLayout works,

Comment: @mKorbel How can flowLayout impact on my problem? If I understand correctly reason for such behaviour(strange dots) was calls of `setText` outside EDT but `setText` isn't thread safe method

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX FlowLayout is default LayoutManager implemented for JPanel by default, this LayoutManager pretty accepting PreferredSize from its JComponents, meanings each of JComponents can have different size on the screen, hmmm compare with GridLayout ....,

Comment: @mKorbel `invokeLater` isn't suitable for my problem(apparently in this case `setText` calls are accumulated in EDT queue. program hangs if delay is small with `invokeLater` (`invokeAndWait` fixes it)

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX that the reasons why I set dealay 10times more than average latency from todays Native OS'es :-)

Comment: @mKorbel I use `Box` which has fixed width (width of widest component inside this box) so `JPanel` with `FlowLayout` doesn't change it's size because it has width of "10000000000000000000000000000000000000" `JLabel`

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX no for String "...777" FlowLayout should be calculated another pixelx ratio as for 0000, this issue is about FontMetrics,

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `setSize()` use `pack()` to take advantage of the component's carefully calculated preferred size. You'll also need to initialize your label:

```
labels[i] = new JLabel("10000000000000000000000000000000000000");
```

Also consider [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of a separate thread.

Addendum: Conveniently, each Swing `Timer` shares a common background thread, and the `actionPerformed()` is called on the event dispatch thread. An alternative is `SwingWorker`, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).

Comment: See also [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: I should call `setText()` regularly for my problem so I need another solution(my code in question is example only)